# Adjusting the content area in 2 column layout when the left column is moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a 2 column layout with left menu having fixed width and i'm following the structure
as given in http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/LayoutGala24.html.

On click of the navigation menu I'm trying to hide it to certain pixels.

How can right content adjust itself automatically when the navigation menu is animated to the left side?

JS

```
$("#navigation").on('click', function() {
  var $el = $(this), animateLeft;
  if(parseInt($el.css('margin-left')) === 0) {
    animateLeft = "-=180px";
  }else{
    animateLeft = "+=180px";
  }
  $(this).animate({
    marginLeft : animateLeft
  },500, function() {
    console.log("anim complete");
  });
});
```

Demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hCmKl

Comment: [Do you want this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LIkrh) Try the link and let me know

Comment: @user3168736, no need for caps

Comment: Even though it is the desired functionality I wouldn't animate the p tag, need a better mechanism to do it, pure css way would be really awesome

Comment: you can not change the width or position of an element with pure css when a jquery event is happening! need to use jQuery!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#navigation").on('click', function() {
  var $el = $(this), animateLeft;
  if(parseInt($el.css('margin-left')) === 0) {
    animateLeft = "-=180px";
  }else{
    animateLeft = "+=180px";
  }
  $(this).animate({
      marginLeft : animateLeft
    },500, function() {
        console.log("anim complete");
    });
  $("#content").animate({
    marginLeft: animateLeft
  }, 500);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ikgnm

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed margin-left , so in your case one solutions is to animate whole content :

```
$("#navigation").on('click', function() {
  var $el = $(this).parent(), animateLeft;
  if(parseInt($el.css('margin-left')) === 0) {
    animateLeft = "-=180";
  }else{
    animateLeft = "+=180";
  }
  $(this).parent().animate({
      marginLeft : animateLeft
    },500, function() {
        console.log("anim complete");
    });

});
```